# adding geom_text to ggfluctuation

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am writing an R function to generate a [fluctuation plot using ggplot2](http://www.r-bloggers.com/heatmap-tables-with-ggplot2/)

```
fluctuation <- function(filename)
    x=read.table(filename,sep=",")

    mydata=melt(x)$value
    mydata=matrix(mydata,ncol=4, byrow=T)
    colnames(mydata) <-c("AA", "AB", "BB","no.call")
    rownames(mydata) <-c("AA", "AB", "BB", "no.call")

    data.melt=melt(mydata)

    names(data.melt)<-c("pgm", "truth", "value")

    p <- ggfluctuation(data.melt)+ xlab("Truth") + ylab("Pgmsnp") 

    p2 <- p  + geom_text(aes(label=data.melt$value),colour="black", main="whole-exome capture")


    return (p2)
```

When I run this code:

```
fluctuation("file.csv")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'data.melt' not found
```

However, if I return p, its fine. So there is some issue with

```
geom_text(aes(label=data.melt$value),colour="black", main="whole-exome capture")
```

But I can't figure it out. I'm still a bit of a ggplot2 newbie. I googled around and found similar questions, but I can't seem to fix my instance. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so familiar with the operation of `` `ggfluctuation() ``, but if it's similar to other ggplot functions, you should change it to

```
p <- ggfluctuation(data.melt)+ xlab("Truth") + ylab("Pgmsnp") 
p2 <- p  + geom_text(aes(label=value),colour="black", main="whole-exome capture")
```

ggplot layers inherit the data frame from the original `ggplot()`, or in this case, `ggfluctuation()` layer. `aes()` looks to the data frame it's inheriting when it maps variables, so in this case, only use `aes(label=value)`.

Comment: Hmmm, `code` Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'value' not found

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is something I don't understand about how R handles functions. If I explicitly glob all my input files and then make the plots by iterating through the list of file inputs I want to make a plot for, it works.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")



files <- dir(getwd(), pattern = "*.csv", full.names = FALSE)

for (i in 1:length(files)) {

    x=read.table(files[i],sep=",")
    mydata=melt(x)$value
    mydata=matrix(mydata,ncol=4, byrow=T)
    colnames(mydata) <-c("AA", "AB", "BB","no.call")
    rownames(mydata) <-c("AA", "AB", "BB", "no.call")

    data.melt=melt(mydata)

    names(data.melt)<-c("pgm", "truth", "value")
    plotname <- paste(files[i], "png", sep=".")
    p <- ggfluctuation(data.melt) + geom_text(aes(label=data.melt$value)) +xlab("Truth") + ylab("Pgmsnp") + theme(axis.text.x= element_text(size=rel(1.5))) + theme(axis.text.y= element_text(size=rel(1.5))) + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = rel(1.5))) + theme(axis.title.y= element_text(size = rel(1.5))) +  opts(title = files[i]) + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(.95)))
    ggsave(p, file=plotname)



}
```